# NSInvocation setArgument not working with simple int32_t

Tags: objective-c, integer, nsinvocation

I am facing an issue while using NSInvocation with arguments which are not objects.
The simple integer value that I pass gets changed to something different.

Here is the method I am invoking:

```
+(NSString*) TestMethod2 :(int32_t) number
{
    NSLog(@"*************** %d ******************", number);
    return @"success";
}
```

And This is how I am calling it :

```
-(void) TestInvocationUsingReflection
{
    id testClass = NSClassFromString(@"TestClass");
    NSMethodSignature * methodSignature = [testClass methodSignatureForSelector:@selector(TestMethod2:)];

    NSInvocation *inv = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:methodSignature];
    [inv setSelector:@selector(TestMethod2:)];
    [inv setTarget:testClass];
    NSNumber * arg = [NSNumber numberWithInt:123456];

    [inv setArgument:&arg atIndex:2]; //arguments 0 and 1 are self and _cmd respectively, automatically set by NSInvocation
    [inv retainArguments];
    NSUInteger length = [[inv methodSignature] methodReturnLength];
    id result = (void *)malloc(length);

    [inv invoke];
    [inv getReturnValue:&result];

}
```

The result is what gets logged is not the simple 123456 value I pass but something like this:

******** *180774176* *************

What is it that I am doing wrong?

I am pretty new to Objective C but, I need to invoke a method at runtime over which I have no control. And it takes int64_t as the argument type.

Please can anyone help?
Thanks....

Comment: Apropos of nothing, please follow convention and start your method names with a lowercase letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing an NSNumber* as the argument, not an int_32t.  The NSNumber happens to wrap the integer, but it's not an integer.

Note that `retainArguments` may expect that the arguments are objects that can be retained.  Its documentation does mention that C strings are copied, but it's not immediately obvious what happens to scalars like an int.  You probably should avoid `retainArguments` and manage retaining and releasing yourself.

Comment: `retainArguments` only retains object pointers (and copies C strings)

Answer (score 6):

You are passing the wrong argument type. Since the method takes an argument of type `int32_t`, that's what you need to pass:

```
int32_t arg = 123456;

[inv setArgument:&arg atIndex:2]; //arguments 0 and 1 are self and _cmd respectively, automatically set by NSInvocation
```